# Cant fetch production db results using Google app engine remote_api

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Hey, I'm trying to work out with /remote_api with a django-patch app engine app i got running.

i want to select a few rows from my online production app locally.

i cant seem to manage to do so, everything authenticates fine, it doesnt breaks on imports, but when i try to fetch something it just doesnt print anything.
Placed the test python inside my local app dir.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#
import os
import sys

# Hardwire in appengine modules to PYTHONPATH
# or use wrapper to do it more elegantly
appengine_dirs = ['myworkingpath']
sys.path.extend(appengine_dirs)
# Add your models to path
my_root_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
sys.path.insert(0, my_root_dir)

from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.ext.remote_api import remote_api_stub
import getpass


APP_NAME = 'Myappname'
os.environ['AUTH_DOMAIN'] = 'gmail.com'
os.environ['USER_EMAIL'] = 'myuser@gmail.com'

def auth_func():
 return (raw_input('Username:'), getpass.getpass('Password:'))

# Use local dev server by passing in as parameter:
# servername='localhost:8080'
# Otherwise, remote_api assumes you are targeting APP_NAME.appspot.com
remote_api_stub.ConfigureRemoteDatastore(APP_NAME,
 '/remote_api', auth_func)

# Do stuff like your code was running on App Engine
from channel.models import Channel, Channel2Operator

myresults = mymodel.all().fetch(10)
for result in myresults:

 print result.key()
```

it doesn't give any error or print anything. so does the remote_api console example google got. when i print the myresults i get [].

Answer (score 2):

App Engine patch monkeypatches the ext.db module, mutilating the kind names. You need to make sure you import App Engine patch from your script, to give it the opportunity to mangle things as per usual, or you won't see any data returned.